# Memcache and Setcookie in php - cannot modify header

Tags: php

I saw something strange in php version 5.5:

This code:

```
1   $memcache = new Memcache();
n   ...
100 $something = $memcache -> get("something");
101 setcookie("myCookie","om-nom-nom-nom",0,0);
```

will return:

```
Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by
(output started at troll.php:100) in troll.php on line 101
```

It seems that `memcache::get()` is changing header. Wtf? Is this an error or maybe I made something wrong?

Comment: It may produce a Notice or something.

Comment: But I do not want this message, whatever it is, an error, or an notice.

Comment: Try without any `echo/print/printf/print_r` in the `n   ...` *header() must be called before any actual output is sent.* - http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php I remember that the first time I fiddled with cookies, it took me 2 days.

Comment: There is no any echo/print/printf/print_r, When I comment 100th line, then error is gone.

Comment: Strange compiler error... ?

Comment: I'm just saying that probably something in your code causes a Notice and it's unclear from your description what exactly. You can take a look in log files or enable display errors.